# ASP.NET public static bool not updating

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `bool` field declared as:

```
public static bool isSaved = false;
```

and a button code (simplified) as:

```
protected void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Some other code

    //UPDATE isSaved
    isSaved = true;        

}//END SaveButton_Click
```

For some reason, `isSaved` is not updated when I click `SaveButton`. Is there a known technical reason for this?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line that says "isSaved = true" and find out if your code is actually executed.

Comment: Why static? It's value may change in another request, make it an instance variable instead.

Comment: Static variables are rarely, if ever, the right tool for the job when it comes to asp - you are aware that the variable would be shared by *all* users of the site, aren't you? And that its value would be "reset" by any application restart

Comment: @RoyDictus: I've added a breakpoint, now what? lol (I'm using VWD2010)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: No, I wasn't aware that all users will update the variable. Should it be private? I want several methods in the code behind page to have access to it.

Comment: You might want to look at state management

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1hkazw7(v=vs.140).aspx

Comment: @RoyDictus: isSaved is being executed in SaveButton but public static bool isSaved is not updated when isSaved=true. Any other ideas to shed?

Comment: @matt2605 Could you please post the whole code, Where have you declared your static variable ? Where else it is being used. Post your full code it might help to shed some light on the matter and also are you sure static variable is right choice?

Comment: When I save, isSaved=true is executed but I have a Label.Text in  Page_Load that displays isSaved=false. Why is  Page_Load executed at the same time SaveButton is executed? Is  Page_Load executed before SaveButton?

Comment: @SurajSingh: I don't know how to update OP. It won't accept a "public" variable unless it's "public static" but as Damien has pointed out this can probably be declared as "private". I can do that later before I host it.

Comment: Please confirm how did you find out `IsSaved` is still false.

Answer (score 1):

Please keep always in mind that by default, if your application does not receive any requests, the application instance will expire and **unload** from memory. All static variables will then be lost! Try to avoid using static variables, if they are not absolutely necessary for your application.

Answer (score 0):

1) Take a look at the ASPNET page lifecycle... there is a specific order of execution of the methods... 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx

In your case, the click event handler will execute after the page load method, that's why you see that it still holds the previous value.

2) Maybe don't use a static variable but use the session/application/viewstate object? depends on your design to decide which one is the most adequate for your needs.

3) Try to render the label text on the pre render stage of the page... you'll have less headache  specially if you're new to ASPNET. Or even better, instead of setting a flag and then using this value for rendering a text... why don't you set the text on the button click event directly? (that might require you to do nothing on page load)